# Cut out a portion of an image (Not resize/thumbnail etc.)

Tags: php, image

Any way I can cut out a part of an existing image, and then save the result as a new image(file)?

Comment: How much do you want to cut out and where do you want to cut it from?

Comment: I am searching up images from urls based on content and I want to create a mosaic from the images found on the pages selected by the algorithm. I would be genearating random numbers for which pixels to cut out, since I want it to run automatically and I'm not trying to get the "best part" of the picture or anything like that.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel Wow man, your attitude really sucks.

Answer (score 5):

[`imagecopy`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopy.php) allows you to specify x,y,w,h arguments for the src image.  Combine this with [`imagecreatetruecolor`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatetruecolor.php) and you should easily be able to achieve what you want.  There is even an example in the documentation for `imagecopy`:

```
// Create image instances
$src = imagecreatefromgif('php.gif');
$dest = imagecreatetruecolor(80, 40);

// Copy
imagecopy($dest, $src, 0, 0, 20, 13, 80, 40);
```

Use [`imagejpeg`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php) or [`imagepng`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagepng.php) to save the image to a file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the gd functions for this ([manual](http://ch.php.net/manual/en/ref.image.php)).

Load the source image (`imagecreatefromstring()` can be useful, so you don't have to specify the type of the image), create an output image (`imagecreatetruecolor()`) and use `imagecopy()` (if you don't want to resize it). At the end use `imagepng()` to output the image, or save it to a file.

Be warned that gd doesn't use image compression in memory, so your PHP process might require lots of RAM when creating a high resolution mosaic. Use `imagefree()` as soon as possible.